# client/server authentiation: React client with C# web api

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api2

I had an app that used an MVC template, prescaffolded with authentication (the one with bootstrap).  I am migrating the project over to Web API and a React Client, but I still need this same functionality.  The MVC authentication used SQL Server.  I really want to do all I can the same, unless something better is possible.  How can I implement authentication/authorization with Web API?  I guess I can store the password in React's state/props, and then maybe pass that into the HTTP calls?

Answer (score 3):

You can generate token using web api and then store it on react front-end in local storage. And whenever you do http call put that token in authorization header and match it from web api backend.

Comment: Sounds promising.  I know how to generate a token and store it in react, but I'm not sure how to put it in the authorization header and match it from web api.  I'll research this part; right now I've mostly just done plain HTTP calls without ever having to do anything with the headers, but good to know that it's possible to do what you have shared.

Comment: Just FYI I am posting the way to put token in the authorization header. You'll just have to write a program to generate and match that token in the backend.

Comment: var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "url",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer  " + token
      },
      success: function (response) {}
      ,
     error : function(response){}